# Where can I find in depth documentation on modifying arcgis stylesheets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, arctoolbox, python-toolbox, xsl

Where can I find in depth documentation on modifying arcgis stylesheets? I have found some of the basics here : 
[Changing tool dialog appearance](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/documenting_tools_and_toolboxes/changing_tool_dialog_appearance.htm)

I want to change the height on one element, the only element in my script. I have a filter value list of 82 counties and I would like to see more than 9 when the tool opens. Usually ESRI documentation is thorough unless it is a topic they expect everyone to know. Is this the case with xsl stylesheets? I think I could figure it out if I just knew what the element was called. does anyone have a suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Maybe someone will prove me wrong, but I believe the help link you attached is the only doc for tool style sheets. I believe the changes you want to make cannot be done (actual parameter changes). But as I dont have a help link that says so, I'll only post as a comment.

Comment: Actually I just re-read the link you posted - it states:  "You cannot customize the parameter controls, only the background image and text."

Comment: @KHibma, wrap it up as an answer, I think..

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I thought that ESRI might have updated the instructions since 9.3 (2008?)... Hoped it was something simple I was missing... No is still a valid answer, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot modify the parameters (size, position, etc).
The style sheets are only for adding an image or some text into the tool dialog background.

Per the [topic referenced](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/documenting_tools_and_toolboxes/changing_tool_dialog_appearance.htm):

> You can change the appearance of a tool dialog, using your company
>   logo as the background image, for example, or adding text. You cannot
>   customize the parameter controls, only the background image and text.
>   The following illustration shows a customized tool dialog with a
>   graphic of the model to be run.

Yes, the topic is from 9.3, but no new development has gone into this area. The help topic is the authoritative source on this subject.

Comment: +1 I looked into changing the look and feel of a Tool dialog about a year ago and after conferring with someone at Esri, came to the conclusion that it wasn't worth the effort. I ended up wrapping my functionality up in a custom wxPython dialog.

Comment: @ChadCooper have an example of that?

Comment: @ian An example of my wx dialog? No, not really. Can't share it and it was about 2K lines of code if I remember correctly. Basically you can use arcpy in the wx GUI, you just can't interact with the map like you can with a Toolbox Tool.

Comment: If the position of the parameters cannot be modified, how did they display the parameters 'X Minimum' and 'X maximum' from example 2 side by side? @ChadCooper

Comment: I have no idea, @Thibailt.

Comment: Because thats how that parameter (extent) appears on the dialog.